# Ranking function in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXNbD.jpg)I have below data in Kusto table .( **Run_Date datetime** and **sensor string** are two column in table)

I have requirement to add autoincrement column in such way that if Run Date or Sensor value gets changed column should incremented by one .

Please refer attached screenshot . I have tried with Rank and Rownumber function in kusto but no luck for me.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `scan` operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scan-operator

```
datatable(run_date:datetime, sensor:string)
[
    datetime(2021-08-05), "A",
    datetime(2021-08-05), "A",
    datetime(2021-08-05), "A",
    datetime(2021-08-05), "B",
    datetime(2021-08-05), "B",
    datetime(2021-09-05), "B",
]
| order by run_date asc
| scan declare (_rank: long = 0) with 
(
    step s1: true => _rank = iff(run_date > s1.run_date or sensor != s1.sensor, s1._rank + 1, s1._rank);
)
```

| run_date | sensor | _rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-05 00:00:00.0000000 | A | 1 |
| 2021-08-05 00:00:00.0000000 | A | 1 |
| 2021-08-05 00:00:00.0000000 | A | 1 |
| 2021-08-05 00:00:00.0000000 | B | 2 |
| 2021-08-05 00:00:00.0000000 | B | 2 |
| 2021-09-05 00:00:00.0000000 | B | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the [row_rank()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rowrankfunction) function

```
datatable(run_date:datetime, sensor:string)
[
    datetime(2021-08-05), "A",
    datetime(2021-08-05), "A",
    datetime(2021-08-05), "A",
    datetime(2021-08-05), "B",
    datetime(2021-08-05), "B",
    datetime(2021-09-05), "B",
]
| extend Day = bin(run_date, 1d)
| extend RankColumn = strcat(Day, sensor)
| order by RankColumn asc 
| extend Rownumber = row_rank(RankColumn)
| project-away RankColumn, Day
```